# Continuous Maps: Totally Boundedness

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Obviously, the image of a separable space under a continuous map is separable again:
$$\overline{A_0}=X:\quad f(X)=f(\overline{A_0})\subseteq\overline{f(A_0)}\subseteq f(X)\quad(\#f(A_0)\leq\#A_0<\infty)$$

What about the image of a totally bounded space under a continuous map?

Comment: What's the image of $(0,1)$ under $x\mapsto 1/x$?

Comment: Ah ^^ of course bounded becomes unbounded

Comment: Can you put it as answer? I would appreciate checking it off from my open questions. :)

Comment: @DavidMitra: What if it is at least bounded: $\|f\|_\infty<\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It need not even be bounded. Take the space $X=(0,1)$ with the usual topology and the continuous function $f:X\rightarrow \Bbb R$ that maps $x$ to $1/x$.

Even if the image is bounded, it need not be totally bounded in the general setting:

Give $\Bbb R$ the bounded metric: $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ if $|x-y|<1$ and $d(x,y)=1$ otherwise. This metric induces the usual topology on $\Bbb R$; so, $f$ defined as above is continuous with respect to this new metric. Also, $f$ maps $(0,1)$ onto $(1,\infty)$, and this set is bounded (any set is), but not totally bounded, with respect to the new metric.

Comment: Nice. Thanks! :) *...btw, the special Arcustangens metric would do so to.*